# Move certain file extension to a different directory in UNIX

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I accidentally ran a script that downloaded the entire works of Shakespeare. I am trying to move all the .html and .txt files to another directory but I am struggling to use the grep and mv command together. If anyone knows the correct line of code or could point me in the right direction to do this I would greatly appreciate it.

I have already created the new directory; I'm just unsure how I can move all the files easily.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). This question does not and should be migrated to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: I love the concept that you "accidentally ran a script that downloaded the entire works of Shakespeare"!

Comment: You're right in suggesting that the execution of the script wasn't an accident. Clearly it wasn't. The accident was downloading the text files to the wrong directory. I'm sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

This should be as simple as...

```
mv *.html *.txt /path/to/another/directory
```

Answer (score 3):

The following should suffice -

```
mv *.html new_folder_name
mv *.txt new_folder_name
```